# Show that the decidability of a statement is undecidable.

Tags: axioms, peano-axioms, decidability

In this system of axioms, it can be shown that A = 5 is undecidable

Axioms: A is a prime number, A is greater than 4, A is less than 8

This is because both A = 5 and A = 7 are consistent with these axioms.

Could you provide a toy example (sort of like the one above) of a statement and a system of axioms in which the statement's decidability is itself undecidable?

[Are there statements that are undecidable but not provably undecidable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/are-there-statements-that-are-undecidable-but-not-provably-undecidable)

This link is similar to my question, but I would like an example using some nonstandard, non-useful system of axioms (sort of like the one above) for simplicity.

Please explain as simply as possible. I am not a math major.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there statements that are undecidable but not provably undecidable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/are-there-statements-that-are-undecidable-but-not-provably-undecidable)

Comment: I was hoping that somebody could think of a toy example (like the one I posed) from which I could develop some understanding. I am unfortunately not familiar with the axioms of ZFC, which are referred to in the link you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Note that no "reasonable" system can prove the independence of any sentence within itself: such a system would a fortiori prove its own consistency (if *anything* is independent of $T$, it must be the case that $T$ can't prove ea contradiction). So we have to ask about undecidability in $T$ being proved or not proved in some further "reasonable" theory $S$. This all makes the question rather messy.

The following result however shows that in a very strong sense we'll never avoid "undecidable undecidability" (without introducing inconsistency, anyways); the key shift is away from *specific axiom systems* and towards *computability-theoretic concerns*, the point being that the latter apply to all ("reasonable") axiom systems at once.

Specifically:

> $(*)\quad$ Assume that (say) first-order Peano arithmetic (PA) is consistent. Then the set $U$ of sentences undecidable in PA is not computable.

In particular, if $T$ is **any** computably axiomatizable theory which doesn't prove any false $\Sigma^0_1$ facts (specifically: doesn't prove "PA proves $\varphi$" when in fact PA does not prove $\varphi$), then there is some sentence $\varphi$ which is independent of PA but whose PA-independence is itself independent of $T$.

The proof of $(*)$ is via the following form of Godel's first incompleteness theorem:

> $(**)\quad$ There is no complete consistent computable theory extending PA.

(More snappily: "PA is *essentially incomplete*.")

To see why $(**)$ implies $(*)$, suppose that $U$ were computable. Then we could build a computable consistent completion of PA as follows. Let $(\varphi_e)_{e\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the usual lexicographic ordering of sentences of arithmetic, and consider the following recursively-defined sequence of sentences:

> We ask $U$ whether the sentence $$\theta_i\equiv(\psi_0\wedge ...\wedge\psi_{i-1})\rightarrow\varphi_i$$ is independent of PA. *(For $i=0$ we set $\theta_0\equiv\varphi_0$.)* If the answer is **yes**, we let $\psi_i=\varphi_i$. If the answer is **no**, we search for either a PA-proof or PA-disproof of $\theta_i$. If we find a PA-proof of $\theta_i$ we let $\psi_i=\varphi_i$; if we find a PA-disproof of $\theta_i$ we let $\psi_i=\neg\varphi_i$.

Assuming $U$ is computable, this whole procedure is computable and defines (by induction) a complete consistent theory extending PA.

---

Can we turn this into a "toy" example?

Well, not really: in order for a theory to even be able to *talk about* provability, it needs to be capable of stating and proving basic facts about finite strings of symbols. In my opinion this really rules out anything I'd consider a "toy" example. In particular, even if we go back to my first paragraph and look for a "toy" theory $T$, some sentence $\varphi$ in the language of $T$, and some "reasonable" theory $S$ such that $\varphi$ is independent of $T$ but $S$ can't prove that (note that that fact about $\varphi,T,$ and $S$ itself is proved within an implicit third theory $U$!), we still have to deal with $S$ itself not being a "toy," and the fact that $S$ will be reasonably powerful also forces $T$ to be complicated.

So I'd say that you're not going to find a toy example of this phenomenon - it's fundamentally about "arithmetized logic," which is inherently a complicated phenomenon.

Comment: Thank you for the question ... and what a nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to think of a simple example of a statement and a set of axioms in which the statement's decidability is undecidable according to the axioms.

I started with the statement "A = 5" and the axioms: A is a prime number, A is greater than 4, A is less than 8.

The statement "A = 5" is undecidable in this system of axioms because A = 5 and A = 7 are consistent with the axioms.

I again used this same logic.

I began with the statement "statement A is undecidable" and the axioms: statement A is a statement, statement A can be written on paper, statement A can be stated in English.

The statement "statement A is undecidable" is undecidable in this system of axioms because both the statements "statement A is undecidable" and "statement A is decidable" are consistent with the axioms.

Since the statement "statement A is undecidable" is undecidable in this system of axioms, this implies that statement A's decidability is undecidable in this system of axioms.