# ZFC + not-CH, can a set with cardinality between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ be defined?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axioms

Continuum hypothesis states, there is no set with cardinality between the integers and the reals.

There is a milestone result, that CH is independent from ZFC. That means, both of ZFC + CH, and ZFC + not-CH are consistent.

What if ZFC and not-CH. Thus, we have an axiom which states, *there* *is* a cardinality between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Can a such set be defined?

Comment: As far as the suggestion goes: [tag:set-theory] should suffice in contrast to [tag:elementary-set-theory].

Comment: By the way: Actually ZFC isn't known to be consistent. See [Asafs comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51992/can-it-be-shown-that-zfc-has-statements-which-cannot-be-proven-to-be-independent?rq=1#comment117145_51992)

Comment: @Meelo If somebody shows a set definition whose cardinality would be between them. Maybe I should have used the word "defined". If it passes better, feel free yourself to fix.

Comment: And by the way, the independence of CH is now over 50 years old. Sure, new compared some things, but not really new in terms of mathematics.

Comment: Seems a little odd to call a fifty-year-old result 'relatively new'!

Comment: How do you feel about 'the set of all countable ordinals'?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am a curious layman. To me, everything is new after around 1900. :-)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think, they are elements of the $\aleph_0$, $\aleph_1$, ... series, whose cardinality is $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Independence means: Both of ZFC + CH and ZFC + not-CH are consistent if and only if ZFC is consistent. Consistence of ZFC isn't needed to be proven.

Comment: @peterh those are cardinals (alephs), not ordinals, and only the first of those is countable.  $\omega_1$ (from Asaf's answer) _is_ the set of countable ordinals, and while that's not a construction per se, it _is_ a somewhat 'graspable' definition.

Comment: A more interesting question is whether, under the failure of the continuum hypothesis, a set *of reals* of intermediate cardinality can be "explicitly defined". The answer is that (consistently) this is not the case.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Well, the brain of a programmer says for that, then CH is _de_ _facto_ true.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Can it be proven, that no such set of reals exists?

Comment: @peterh Under appropriate large cardinal assumptions it can be proved that any set of reals in $L(\mathbb R)$ is either countable or of the same size as $\mathbb R$. "Belonging to $L(\mathbb R)$" is a (more than generous) formalization of "being explicitly definable". The result is stronger, in the sense that $L(\mathbb R)$ can be replaced by larger classes, and we actually get a rich structure theory of set of reals. Of course, the relevant large cardinal assumptions are not provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, although many set theorists would agree that they are part of the "correct" axiomatization.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by $L(\mathbb Z)$. Your use of $\mathbb R\setminus L(\mathbb R)$ is also incorrect. Anyway, no, the continuum hypothesis is not a theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I probably misunderstood! But thank you the answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In some sense, yes, you can always construct a set of size $\aleph_1$. Specifically $\omega_1$ is a set of size $\aleph_1$. And if the continuum hypothesis fails, it serves as a counterexample.

You might want to ask whether or not you can construct a set of real numbers of this particular size, and the answer to that will depend on your notion of "construct", but if you mean define "in a reasonable way" the answer is consistently negative.

Comment: Well, I should have used the word "defined", I fixed! Thank you!

Comment: Ok, but under "between" I understood a set, for which $\aleph_0 < |S| < \aleph_1$.

Comment: This means that you didn't understand the definition of $\aleph_1$. There is no such set, by definition. Regardless to the continuum hypothesis or otherwise.

Comment: Yes, mea culpa. What if I say: $\aleph_0 < |S| < 2^{\aleph_0}$? Can a such set $S$ be defined from ZFC + not-CH?

Comment: Then I will say, read my answer.

Comment: Thank you your wonderful answer. My only question what remains: what is $\omega_1$?

Comment: It is the smallest uncountable ordinal, equivalently the set of all countable ordinals, equivalently the canonical set of cardinality $\aleph_1$. If you look around you could find several answers explaining it in great detail. I'd give you some links but I'm already in bed. And doing so from my phone is a pain in the wrist.

Comment: On the other hand, it is simple to define a partition of $\mathbb R$ into $\aleph_1$ many disjoint nonempty sets.