# What mean $L(\mathbb{R})$ and $L(\mathbb{R})^*$?

Tags: cardinals

I found them relating a cardinality question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159395/zfc-not-ch-can-a-set-with-cardinality-between-aleph-0-and-2-aleph-0-b).

Does it have anything to do with regularity/computability?

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo should be able to answer, since this question directly concerns [a comment by him](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159395/zfc-not-ch-can-a-set-with-cardinality-between-aleph-0-and-2-aleph-0-b#comment2364274_1159395).

Comment: It is _not_ an abandoned question. I am still waiting an answer and I am ready to accept/upvote it.

Comment: Where do you see L(R)* on that page?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I flagged for a mod to search in the deleted comments, but it didn't exist. I can't remember, where is it from, but I am 99% sure, it is from a reasonable source.

Comment: Maybe you mean $L(\Bbb R^*)$, which has meaning in the context of models of AD?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Likely this was what I've seen. Thanks - these infos are already enough to learn after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$L(\mathbb{R})$ is the the constructible universe built over $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. we can use the "real" reals as parameters). Here is the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L(R)) and [here](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/wjm/files/inner_model_history.pdf) is some information on its construction (beginning on page 3 ~ relative construction). I have never seen $L(\mathbb{R})^*$ before, it also does not appear on the page you have linked to. Then again, I am not a set theorist.